# jQuery FadeIn text in IE7/IE8 : text aliased during animation

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, opacity, fadein

I have trouble to make a good use of jQuery fadeIn() or fadeOut() for text divs in IE(both 7 and 8), as you can see in this example : http://jsbin.com/etatu3/5   (see the code here : http://jsbin.com/etatu3/5/edit )

I did some research and it seems it's because of filter opacity.

I tried using

```
animate({filter: (opacity = 50)},1000);
```

But of course it didn't work. I checked the hasLayout, it's on true.

Is there any solution for the text not to be aliased during the fade animation, because it's quite ugly for big titles like this ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Edit : just to be clear, as you can see in the example I included, I already use removeAttribute('filter'); This does the job **after** the animation, not **during** it.

Comment: This may not be relevant, but jQuery itself will adapt to the needs of IE, so you can just use "opacity" by itself with fractional values from 0 (invisible) to 1 (fully opaque).

Comment: Look at the example I provided, the problem is fadeIn() or fadeOut() , that are basically shortcuts for animate({opacity : 0/1)},1000); do some ugly text animation cause it loses cleartype during animation. I would like to know if there is a solution for this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a white background color to the element, it improves the animation but still does not make it perfect

http://jsbin.com/etatu3/17

Comment: It is way better ;) Thanks for the trick, I barely see the difference with FF now.